# Connect React Native App to Azure IoT Service

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am fairly new to React Native, but I created a simple app that has a button and a text that changes when the button is clicked. However, I want to connect to the IoT hub and receive information from the hub.

I am having issues currently with the connection. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Dimensions, Alert, Text, View, Image, Button} from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

    'use strict';
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');
var connectionString = 'connection string';
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt);

// Create a message and send it to the IoT hub every second
setInterval(function(){
  // Simulate telemetry.
  var temperature = 20 + (Math.random() * 15);
  var message = new Message(JSON.stringify({
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: 60 + (Math.random() * 20)
  }));

  // Add a custom application property to the message.
  // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
  message.properties.add('temperatureAlert', (temperature > 30) ? 'true' : 'false');

  console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());

  // Send the message.
  client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('send error: ' + err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log('message sent');
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

The above part is a `Node.js` code, but I want to use it in a React application. How do I use Node packages in React?

I am getting the following error: `Could not connect to development server.`

Thanks.

Comment: hi have you got any success?

Answer (score 1):

As in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907041/how-to-use-node-js-code-in-react-native-app/), I would suggest you take a look at [Azure IoT Starter Kit Companion](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/azure-iot-starterkit-companionapp/), which is a sample **React Native** application that helps you get your **IoT device** connected to an **IoT Hub** on **iOS**, **Android** and **Windows**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-starterkit-companionapp

Answer (score 1):

Small point,  you should NOT publish your connection strings.  This is a rather large security issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907041/how-to-use-node-js-code-in-react-native-app/), the Azure IoT Hub Device SDK needs a Node.js runtime, which does not exists within the React Native app.

There is a plugin called [nodejs-mobile-react-native](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-react-native) for React Native that brings in the Node.js runtime and enables you to run Node.js apps alongside your React Native application.

I have written a [detailed blog post](https://bnek.github.io/code/2020/06/10/Bring-Azure-IoT-to-Mobile-Phones-using-react-native.html) about this topic outlining the steps necessary to achieve this.